# returning a value not working correctly? (basic Java)

Tags: java

In this program, I must have user input value for variable (N). In method 1, user will input 10 numbers into an array. In method 2, it will compare variable (N) and save all numbers larger than that variable to (greaterNums) variable. Having some return and sending problems, even though I have read chapter over and over. Someone please point me in the right direction!

Problem 1: greaterNums variable value isn't correct after the arguments in method 2.
Problem 2: greaterNums variable isn't returning to main method to be displayed.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Project6Walker
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;        //Establish array size
        int n;                            //Holds comparable value
        String input;                     //Holds user input

        int[] array = new int[ARRAY_SIZE]; //Establishes array

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number. Must not be a negative number.");
        n = Integer.parseInt(input);     //Gather value N

        while (n < 0)           //INPUT VALIDATION for N
        {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Must not be a negative number. Please try again.");
            n = Integer.parseInt(input);
        }

        gatherArrayInformation(array, input);             //Calls method 1
        compareArrayInformation(array, n);                //Calls method 2
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The numbers in the array that are "+
                "greater than " +n+ " are (greaterNums goes here).");  //Final output of information

        /**
          This method will prompt the user to enter 10 numbers in the array
          that will be compared to the value N
         */
    }

    public static int[] gatherArrayInformation(int[] array, String input)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter series of " + array.length + "  numbers");
        for (int i= 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number " + (i + 1) + ":");
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(input);

            while (array[i] < 0)
            {
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number " + (i + 1) + " cannot be negative.      Try     Again.");
                array[i] = Integer.parseInt(input);
            }
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
        return array;
    }

    /**
      This method will take the 10 numbers from method 1,
      and see which numbers are larger than N
      @return greaterNums
     */
    public static int compareArrayInformation(int[] array, int n)
    {
        int greaterNums = 0;
        for (int i= 1; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] > n)
                greaterNums = array[i];
            System.out.println(greaterNums);
        }
        return greaterNums;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a bit of time to format your code pleasantly, adjusting the indentation and ideally trying to avoid readers having to scroll horizontally. Currently the code is really hard to read due to the lack of proper indentation. Next, give us sample input, expected output and actual output - otherwise we won't know how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: in compareArrayInformation(), any value that is greater than n is assigned to greaterNums, overwriting any previous value that was greater than n.  So while you are printing all the values greater than n, you are only returning the last value in the array that's greater than n.  You probably want to add those values to an array and return all of them.

Comment: You currently have: for (int i= 1; i < array.length; i++)....Why don't you start with i=0.

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited the horizontal issue. The output is simply supposed to show which numbers in the array are greather than (N). When i use the System.out.print(greaterNums) in the second method, the output is strange. Also, when i try to add greaterNums to my final output it says the variable cannot be found, assuming it's not returning correctly to the main method.

Comment: You're returning `greaterNums`... but you're ignoring the return value when you *call* the method.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 2: When you return greaterNums, as your code currently stands, it's just returning the array member with the highest index that was bigger than n.

Answer (score 0):

Array indices start from 0.

```
public static List<Integer> compareArrayInformation(int[] array, int n)
{
    List<Integer> greaterNums = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) // Count from 0
    {
        if (array[i] > n) {
            int greaterNum = array[i];
            System.out.println(greaterNum);
            greaterNums.add(greaterNum);
        }
     }
     return greaterNums;
}
```

And to collect all greater numbers, one better uses no fixed sized array, `int[]`, but a `List<Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

this program will work with i set to 0 not one but it will of course only show THE LAST GREATER NUMBER not nums hope that is what you wanted.

```
 public static int compareArrayInformation(int[] array, int n)
{
int greaterNums = 0;

for (int i= 0; i < array.length; i++)//not one 
 {
 if (array[i] > n)

    greaterNums = array[i];
    System.out.println(greaterNums);

 }
 return greaterNums;
 }
```

maybe you want this?

```
 public static int[] compareArrayInformation(int[] array, int n)
{
int[] greaternums=new int[array.length];
int upto=0;

for (int i= 0; i < array.length; i++)//not one 
 {
 if (array[i] > n)

    greaternums[upto] = array[i];
    System.out.println(array[i]);
    upto++;
 }
 return Arrays.copyOf(greaternums, upto);
 }
```

Comment: When i test your edit to my second method, it shows an error on line:

  "  greaterNums[upto] = array[i];  "

It says greaterNums cannot be found

Comment: sorry i must have messed up one second here

Comment: nums is Nums sorry about that try now

Answer (score 0):

Replace your function `compareArrayInformation` to below

```
public static int compareArrayInformation(int[] array, int n)
{
  int[] greaterNums = new int[10];  

  for (int i= 0; i < array.length; i++)
   {
     if (array[i] > n)
      { 
      greaterNums.add(array[i]);
      }

   }
  return greaterNums;
}
```

and in your `main` method change the below lines FROM

`compareArrayInformation(array, n);`
`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The numbers in the array that are "+`
                `"greater than "` `+n+ " are (greaterNums goes here).");`

TO

```
int[] greaterNumsArray = compareArrayInformation(array, n); 
StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer("");

for (int i=0; i<greaterNumsArray.length; i++){
  sBuffer.append(greaterNumsArray[i]);
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The numbers in the array that are "+
            "greater than " +n+ " are "+sBuffer );
```